# My program writes the data to file successfully, but the URL data needs to be checked by my link checker. Node.js

Tags: node.js, fetch, linkchecker

https://github.com/strawberries73/OSD600-Journey-on-rocky-trails

I need the data converted to show URLs only for my Link Check to work.  I have tried another solution but  the new code solution deletes the conversion before it gets read.  If there is a way to pull the URL's and get them to be written to a different file or the same file, my link checker would work.

```
 // ExitCode
    process.on("SIGTERM", () => {
        server.close(() => {
          console.log("Program is terminated");
        });
      });
    
    //Flag labeling each URL as a good or bad
    const _label = ({
        good: "GOOD",
        bad: "BAD"
    });
    
    //const getTelescope = fetch('http:/') data
    async function getTelescopeData(){
        //fetching data from local host
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/posts").then(response => {
            return response.json();
            }).then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            
    
            //truncate the data and write to file
            fs.truncate("telescopeData.txt", 0, function() {
                for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    fetch(`http://localhost:3000${data[i].url}`)
                    .then(res => {
                        return res.json();
                        }).then(telescopeData => {
                            //Append to telescopeData.txt
                            fs.appendFile("telescopeData.txt", telescopeData.html,
                             (err) => {
                                if(err) {
                                    console.log(err)
                                    .then.process(); //Termination 
                                    } 
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    });
            }
        );
    }
    
    getTelescopeData(); //Data fetched
    
    
    if(process.argv.length==2){
        greetingMessage();
        console.log("Hello");
    }
    else{
        const filePath=path.join(__dirname,process.argv[2]);
        fs.readFile(filePath,"utf-8",(err,data)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log("Fail to read file",err);
            }
            else{
                const validUrl=data.match(/(http|https)(:\/\/)([\w+\-&@`~#$%^*.=/?:]+)/gi);
                validUrl.forEach((url)=>{
                fetch(url,{method:"HEAD",timeout:2000})
                .then((res)=>{
                    if(res.status==200)
                    console.log(res.status,url.green,_label.good.rainbow);
                    else if(res.status==400||res.status==404)
                    console.log(res.status,url);
                    else console.log(res.status,url)
                    .then.process(); //Termination 
    
                })
                .catch((error)=>{
                    console.log("404",url.red, _label.bad.bgRed);
                });
            });
            }
        });
    }
```

[Output of Data in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I3Yz.png)

New Code tried, only it deletes the input after it has been written to file.

```
// ExitCode
process.on("SIGTERM", () => {
    server.close(() => {
        console.log("Program is terminated");
    });
});

//Flag labeling each URL as a good or bad
const _label = ({
    good: "GOOD",
    bad: "BAD"
});

//const getTelescope = fetch('http:/') data
async function getTelescopeData() {

    //fetching data from local host
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/posts").then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
        console.log(data);

        //truncate the data and write to file
        fs.truncate("telescopeData.txt", 0, function () {
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                fetch(`http://localhost:3000${data[i].url}`)
                    .then(res => {
                        return res.json();
                    }).then(telescopeData => {
                        //Append to telescopeData.txt
                        fs.appendFile("telescopeData.txt", telescopeData.html,
                            (err) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err)
                                        .then.process(); //Termination 
                                }
                            });
                    });
            }
        });

        // its not reading the file for some reason. File is empty when I add this.
        fs.readFile("telescopeData.txt", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Fail to read file", err);
            }
            else {

                console.log(data);
                console.log("^^^");
                const validUrl = data.match(/(http|https)(:\/\/)([\w+\-&@`~#$%^*.=/?:]+)/gi);
                console.log(validUrl);
                console.log("^^^");
                validUrl.forEach((url) => {
                    fetch(url, { method: "HEAD", timeout: 2000 })
                        .then((res) => {
                            if (res.status == 200)
                                console.log(res.status, url.green, _label.good.rainbow);
                            else if (res.status == 400 || res.status == 404)
                                console.log(res.status, url);
                            else console.log(res.status, url)
                                .then.process(); //Termination 

                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log("404", url.red, _label.bad.bgRed);
                        });
                });
            }
        });
    } // then ends
    );
}

if (process.argv.length == 2) {
    greetingMessage();
    console.log("Hello");
} else if (process.argv[2] == "--telescope") {
    console.log("Telescope");
    getTelescopeData();
}
else {
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, process.argv[2]);
    fs.readFile(filePath, "utf-8", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Fail to read file", err);
        }
        else {
            const validUrl = data.match(/(http|https)(:\/\/)([\w+\-&@`~#$%^*.=/?:]+)/gi);
            validUrl.forEach((url) => {
                fetch(url, { method: "HEAD", timeout: 2000 })
                    .then((res) => {
                        if (res.status == 200)
                            console.log(res.status, url.green, _label.good.rainbow);
                        else if (res.status == 400 || res.status == 404)
                            console.log(res.status, url);
                        else console.log(res.status, url)
                            .then.process(); //Termination 

                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log("404", url.red, _label.bad.bgRed);
                    });
            });
        }
    });
}





async function getTelescopeData(body, url){
    //fetching data from local host
    const localRegex= /https?:\/\/localhost:[0-9]*/;
    const baseurl=url.match(localRegex);
    return JSON.parse(body).map((i)=>{return baseurl[0]+i.url;
        })
    }
```